# When using nginx, how can I get the $scheme using lua?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

nginx provides a variable named `scheme` which contains either `http` or `https`. In a reverse proxy I'm writing using [openresty](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module), I want to access that variable from a `content_by_lua_block`. I know there are variables to get request headers (`ngx.req.get_headers()`) or other elements, but how can I get the request scheme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's just a matter of using [`ngx.var.VARIABLE`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#ngxvarvariable) prefix. In my case, it will be `ngx.var.scheme`.